# Best SIMPLE database structure for my web app with resources, categories, and tags

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have been teaching myself to code for about 6 months now and am building my 1st web app for practice.

I'm aiming to build my own very simple cms to store my resources in the database and serve them back up on the page.

I will have resources -
each resource will be assigned to only 1 of 3 categories - 
each resource can have multiple tags.
Ultimately the user can navigate to each category page and on that page filter the resources by tag.

I am struggling with how to design the DB.

Without a doubt I will have a resources table. 
Should I store the category assignment directly in this table (since each resource can only have 1) or is it better to create a relationship with a category table for this? I've done a lot of research on tag schema's and some seem a bit too complicated for me at this beginner stage. What is the simplest way to store multiple tags for a resource. 2 tables? How would this be accomplished?

I am using PHP and mySQL.

Comment: way to broad for S.O

Comment: @Dagon - is there a better place / other website that would be a better place for this type of question?

Comment: @BriannaVay I posted a quick explanation because in this format this question will probably be closed. This is a giant subject, but I'm sure that if you research more into the term "many-to-many, one-to-many, database relationships", and "mysql JOIN" you will find what you need. Many examples on the internet.

Comment: thank you so much for your help @sidyll I've done a bunch or research and i agree fro the tags i will probably have to set up 3 tables, to be honest it's just very intimidating for a beginner. Not really creating them but eventually having to update and query them. Lots to learn! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @BriannaVay . These kind of relationships can appear to be complex, but it is not difficult to understand. And once you do two or three operations with them it becomes easier. Sometimes one procedure or another will need to be done in multiple steps, don't find this strange. And in the future while you're implementing, if you have questions you can always come back with a more precise one, where you present your DB design and operation, and what you have tried and why eventually it didn't work. This is the most accepted format here. Success, Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For the category, since you have only one per resource, store on the same table. This is a one to one relationship.

For tagging, you might need two additional tables because this is a many to many relationship (each resource can have multiple tags and each tag can be assigned to multiple resources). One table is to store the tag name and its ID. Another table is to store the relations. This one has two columns, one for the tag ID and other for the resource ID.

Quick example:

```
id | resource | category
---+----------+----------
 1 |   rice   |    24
 2 |   apple  |    42

id | tag 
---+-------
 1 | fruit
 2 | cereal
 3 | food

id_t | id_p
-----+------
  2  |  1
  1  |  2
  3  |  1
  3  |  2
```

Then you can query the tables and `JOIN` them to get the desired results.

Comment: i suppose if this is the answer the OP needs, then its not to broad . :-)

Comment: @Dagon thanks. Since the question is tagged with database design, I think this fits. But I don't deny that it is a broad thing, both question and my answer :-)

Comment: well if its accepted i'll withdraw my close vote (for what its worth)